# Funny font in the build messages in Codeblocks using g++-4 (Cygwin) as compiler

Tags: g++, cygwin, codeblocks

I am using CodeBlocks 10.05 with Cygwin 1.7 to compile some C++ codes. The operating system is WinXP SP3. The compiler used is g++ 4.5.3.

When I build the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned long long a = 12345678901234;
    printf("%u\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

it outputs the following in the build log:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Zhi Ping\Desktop\UVa\143\main.cpp||In function â€˜int main()â€™:|
C:\Documents and Settings\Zhi Ping\Desktop\UVa\143\main.cpp|9|warning: format â€˜%uâ€™ expects type â€˜unsigned intâ€™, but argument 2 has type â€˜long long unsigned intâ€™|
C:\Documents and Settings\Zhi Ping\Desktop\UVa\143\main.cpp|9|warning: format â€˜%uâ€™ expects type â€˜unsigned intâ€™, but argument 2 has type â€˜long long unsigned intâ€™|
||=== Build finished: 0 errors, 2 warnings ===|
```

I do not know why CodeBlocks prints the â€˜ etc. symbols. Is there a way for CodeBlocks to properly display the characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin defaults to the UTF-8 encoding, whereas it looks like CodeBlocks assumes that output is in CP1252. Furthermore, since Cygwin tells it that UTF-8 is available, gcc uses separate left and right versions of quote characters instead of the usual ASCII ones. The result is what you're seeing. There are two ways to tackle this: either tell CodeBlocks to use UTF-8, or tell gcc to stick to ASCII by setting `LANG=C`. I don't know how to do either of these in CodeBlocks though.

Comment: I added an environment variable with that name and value and it worked. Maybe other programs will see the variable too, but so far I've had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following Environment Variable to your computer:

```
LANG=C
```

In Windows 7, you can add it by going to Computer > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables, then "New...". The menus should be similar in Windows XP.

I hope it's ok to answer an old question. This happened to me today as well, and it took me a while to fix it.